# Cannot set setstate in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Can anybody explain what im doing wrong here, my setState console is returning undefined where the first console is returning right values

```
return firebase.database().ref('Users/Trainers/').on('value', (snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
                // var childKey= childSnapshot.key;
                var childData= childSnapshot.val();
                var childEmail = childData.email;
                var childfirstName = childData.firstName;
                var childlastName = childData.lastName;
                var childTrainers = childfirstName + ' ' + childlastName + ' ' + childEmail;
                 console.log(childTrainers);
            })
            this.setState({
                Trainers: snapshot.val().childTrainers
            })
            console.log(this.state.Trainers)
        })
```

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous, you can't console log it on the next line. Use the second argument in `setState`, a callback where you can access udpated state

Comment: Thanks i understand, i do it like `this.setState({
                Trainers: snapshot.val().childTrainers
            }, console.log(this.state.Trainers))` but now its returning me nothing

Comment: Have you bound the setState function in your constructor?
And use the arrow function for every functions in forEach also

Comment: @RagibHuda yaa...

Answer (score 0):

Okay ive done, and the correct answer is

```
return firebase.database().ref('Users/Trainers/').on('value', (snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
                // this.setState({
                //     childEmail = childSnapshot.val().email
                // })
                // var childKey= childSnapshot.key;
                var childData= childSnapshot.val();
                var childEmail = childData.email;
                var childfirstName = childData.firstName;
                var childlastName = childData.lastName;
                var childTrainers = childfirstName + ' ' + childlastName + ' ' + childEmail;
                 //console.log(childTrainers);
                 this.setState({
                     Trainers: [childTrainers]
                 }, console.log(this.state.Trainers))
            })
        })
```

All values are retrieving